# R: Error bars are not printed in ggplot on a log scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following example dataset:

```
Sample,Zeitpunkt,Target,NRQ,SD
"Ctrl","42wk","Ccl12",0.02288218,0.02693519
```

I need to use a logarithmic y scale. The MWE looks as follows:

```
library("ggplot2")

Cc <- ggplot(test, aes(x=Sample, y=NRQ, fill=Zeitpunkt, ymin=NRQ-SD, ymax=NRQ+SD)) 
Cc <- Cc + geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") 
Cc <- Cc + scale_y_log10(breaks=c(0.01,0.1,1,10,100), limits=c(0.00001,200))
Cc <- Cc + annotation_logticks(base = 10, sides="l")
Cc <- Cc + guides(fill = guide_legend(keywidth = 0.6, keyheight = 0.6))
Cc <- Cc + geom_errorbar(linetype=1, size=0.5, width=0, position=position_dodge(0.9))
```

Which should produce error bars. But it doesn't:

[image]

What we've found so far is:

1. The error occurs if the error value is larger than the mean value (in this example `0.02288218 < 0.02693519`.
2. It also occurs if the errorbars are hitting the limits of the plot.

The `dodge` command is included because we need it for the actual plot containing more data, so it would be nice to have it included. **Is there a way to plot the error bars in this kind of plot?**

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is quite old, but I had a similar problem and 
I found a solution. When I added `+ scale_X_log10()` to my `ggplot`, all of my error bars were thrown off. I also had `+ position=position_dodge(2.5)` added to the plot. Either eliminating this command, or reducing it to `position=position_dodge(.025)` returned my error bars to the appropriate location. However, I was not able to replicate this issue when scaling the y axis to log10.